# Unable to execute a node module within PHP

Tags: php, node.js, unix

After installing the necessary modules, the following command

```
azure account -help
```

works as expected. However, when I invoke the same command from inside PHP using exec().

```
exec('azure account -help',$output,$responseCode)
```

and print the output, I get

> $output: [] (empty array) and $responseCode: 8

I've tried executing the module using the command 'node'. Ex

> node /usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/bin/azure.js account -help

This also works on command line but not through PHP's exec.

Edit: Redirecting the stderr with the following command:

```
exec('azure account -help &2>1',$output,$responseCode)
```

gives these details:

> ,E === undefined) && (process.env.HOMEDRIVE === undefined))) {throw new Error(,                                                                    ^,Error: HOME not found, unable to store Streamline callback cache,    at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/streamline/lib/compiler/compile.js:278:90),    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26),    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10),    at Module.load (module.js:356:32),    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12),    at Module.require (module.js:364:17),    at require (module.js:380:17),    at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/streamline/lib/compiler/register.js:28:15),    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26),    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)

What can I try to debug this further?

Comment: php is not bash and won't search azure command in PATH. Try calling it, using full path to azure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was solved by invoking exec() and providing a HOME env variable:

> exec('HOME=/tmp/ azure account -help 2>&1');

Answer (score 0):

php do not know about node , so make sure you specify full path of nodejs something like

```
exec('c:/nodejs/node.exe mynode_scripts.js',$retr_err,$retr_val);
```